# Error converting data type from varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following update query running nightly which updates GIS information in a SQL spatial database (GIS) to another database (LIVE).  This update has worked without issue for a few months and all of a sudden today it fails with

> "Error converting data type from varchar to numeric."

```
update LIVE.dbo.PT001
Set
    LIVE.dbo.pt001.dlonglegal_1 = Left(GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection,2),
    LIVE.dbo.pt001.dlonglegal_2 = SUBSTRING(GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection,3,CHARINDEX('-',GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection+'-')-3),
    LIVE.dbo.pt001.dlonglegal_3 = SUBSTRING(GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection,CHARINDEX('-',GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection+'-')+1,1),
    LIVE.dbo.pt001.dlonglegal_4 = SUBSTRING(GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection,CHARINDEX('-',GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection+'-')+3,1),
    LIVE.dbo.pt001.dlonglegal_5 = right(GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection,1)
From GIS.dbo.parcel inner Join
LIVE.dbo.PT001 on GIS.dbo.parcel.roll = LIVE.dbo.pt001.dROLLNMBR
where GIS.dbo.parcel.roll = LIVE.dbo.PT001.drollnmbr AND
GIS.dbo.parcel.quartersection is not null
```

The quartersection information is stored in the parcel table as nvarchar(30) with the following format:

```
NW12-5-6E
```

In the destination table it would be stored as char(15) and as follows:

```
dlonglegal_1 = NW
dlonglegal_2 = 12
dlonglegal_3 = 5
dlonglegal_4 = 6
dlonglegal_5 = E
```

I've tried casting the numeric fields as numeric without success. I'm stumped as why the update started failing today as there have been no changes to the database structure in a long time.

Comment: If structure is the same then it's probably the data, if you have something like 'NW12- 5-6E' that'd fail.

Comment: You have something in there that is doing an implicit conversion from varchar to numeric. We don't know the table structures so it is just guessing. It might be one of the dlonglegal columns (those looke like they could stand the be normalized but that is another topic). Or it might be one of the columns in your join predicate. BTW, why is there a where clause in this query at all? EVERY row returned will always meet that criteria because the inner join is exactly the same.

Comment: What are the types of `roll` and `dROLLNMBR`? Is one of them numeric and the other text? If so, the server would have to convert the values of one column to the other in order to perform the join. This would also mean that performance already suffers because this conversion probably prevented the optimizer from using indexes on the text column

Comment: My suggestions would be to check the precision of the dlonglegal column.  if you expect NW12-5-6E and you actually have NW12-55-6E it messes up the whole substring.  Perhaps do a TRY_CONVERT and then look for NULLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like artm suggested I thought the most likely scenario was an issue with the data but everything was correct.  I ran the update for each column separately and it worked for each one.  I then ran the full query and it completed without issue.  I'm not sure what the final problem was but evidently it appears to be working again.  I thank you for your input.